Android keystore "LSKF is not setup for the user"
I have a problem with some Android devices, where the key pair generation failed with "java.security.ProviderException: Failed to generate key pair." caused by "Failed to handle super encryption.", "Failed to super encrypt with LskfBound key.", "LSKF is not setup for the user."
Resetting the lock screen pin/password didn't help.
As far as I could analyse the error, LSKF is the lock screen knowledge factor, the pin/password used for unlocking the device lock screen.
Full exception (from Samsung S21, Android 14):
Java.security.ProviderException: Failed to generate key pair.
    ...
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8043) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:17816) ~[na:0.0]
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1218) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8020) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:31850) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8893) ~[na:0.0]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) ~[na:0.0]
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608) ~[na:0.0]
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103) ~[na:0.0]
 Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Keystore not initialized (internal Keystore code: 3 message: system/security/keystore2/src/security_level.rs:701: In generate_key. 10012
 
 Caused by:
 0: system/security/keystore2/src/security_level.rs:209
 1: system/security/keystore2/src/security_level.rs:186: Failed to handle super encryption.
 2: system/security/keystore2/src/super_key.rs:758: Failed to super encrypt with LskfBound key.
 3: system/security/keystore2/src/super_key.rs:718: LSKF is not setup for the user.
 4: Error::Rc(r#UNINITIALIZED))
    at android.security.KeyStore2.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore2.java:399) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.security.KeyStoreSecurityLevel.handleExceptions(KeyStoreSecurityLevel.java:60) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.security.KeyStoreSecurityLevel.generateKey(KeyStoreSecurityLevel.java:161) ~[na:0.0]
    at android.security.keystore2.AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.generateKeyPair(AndroidKeyStoreKeyPairGeneratorSpi.java:651) ~[na:0.0]
 24 common frames omitted

I don't have direct access to the device and was not able to reproduce the same error on any test device.
What I know about the device:

strong biometrics are set (finger print)
a string password is set (PASSWORD_COMPLEXITY_HIGH)

The relevant key generation parameter:
setUserAuthenticationRequired(true)
setUserAuthenticationParameters(0,KeyProperties.AUTH_BIOMETRIC_STRONG)
setUserConfirmationRequired(false)
setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256, KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)

The error occurs on the generation of RSA and EC keys. There are fallbacks for only SHA256 and time-based key authentication, but neither seems to work here.
Does anybody have the same problems? I found some similar problem on the net but without any answer.
Can anybody reproduce the problem?
I tried to remove and set the lock screen factors for different device models from different manufactures.
For some older devices you can set a finger print, remove the pin afterwards and keep the finger print data, but that didn't result in the expected error.
I've added retry logic to the key generation process for different key types (RSA,EC), differente hash algorithm (SHA256, SHA512) and authentication timeouts (per-use-keys and time-based-keys). The error occurs on all of the variants for these devices.

Did you manage to find solution to this problem? @pHagi

no, still having the same issues with some devices
